# How to implement "all check" button on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a button to check all checkboxes. The problem is that my "*all check*" button doesn't work to check off all checkboxes when I click the button.

How can I do this?

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
    .controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.allcheck = function(){
            angular.forEach($scope.checkboxes, function(item){
             item.selected = event.target.checked;
        });
        };
    }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>AngularJS</h1>
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <button ng-click="allcheck()">all check</button>
        <input type="checkbox">a
        <input type="checkbox">b
        <input type="checkbox">c
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start with Angular you should think and do in angular.

First you define your model:

```
$scope.selected = [false, false, false];
```

Then you render your model into view, using repeat. (I don't remember the syntax)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in selected">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item" />
</div>
```

Then you implement check all by just simply changing the model.

```
$scope.checkAll = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selected.length; i++) {
         $scope.selected[i] = true;
    }
}
```

Don't think like you are working with JQuery, think like MVC.